# payment is completed without the sender logging in to paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using this gem [**active_paypa_adaptive_payment**](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) for payments system on a web page.

**preapproval_payment** feature is working fine and I have a **preapproval_key** inside my database.

Now I want execute the agreement with my **preaproval_key**.

I have been checking `cancel_preapproval` method and it does work fine.

I dont need go to paypal page with `cancel_preapproval` method in my `cancel_order` method in my order controller.i.e.:

```
preapproval_key = @order.payment.preapproval_key
 response = gateway.cancel_preapproval(:preapproval_key => preapproval_key)
   respond_to do |format|
      if response.ack == "Success"
       @order.update_attributes
           format.html { redirect_to user_orders_url(current_user), notice: t(".cancel_order_success") }
       else
           format.html { redirect_to user_orders_url(current_user), alert: t(".cancel_order_wrong") }
      end
    end
```

How can I execute the agreement with my `preapproval_key` for transfer funds from sender account to receiver account?

is it possible this feature for execute the agreement instead cancel the agreement with my `preapproval_key`?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add the field `:preapproval_key` to the response. Something like, in your action:

```
def your_action

recipients = [{:email => 'receiver_email',
                 :amount => some_amount,
                 :primary => true},
                {:email => 'receiver_email',
                 :amount => recipient_amount,
                 :primary => false}
                 ]
  response = gateway.setup_purchase(
    :return_url => url_for(:action => 'action', :only_path => false),
    :cancel_url => url_for(:action => 'action', :only_path => false),
    :ipn_notification_url => url_for(:action => 'notify_action', :only_path => false),
    :receiver_list => recipients
    :preapproval_key => "your_preapproval_key_here",
  )

respond_to do |format|
   if object.update_attributes
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t(".success") }
   else
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, alert: t(".wrong") }
   end
  end

end
```

Note that you must have `preapproval_key` available. You can save it to your database when you make preapproved payment or you can get it with the api [**PreapprovalDetails**](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPreapprovalDetails)

With this way you can make a pay with a preapproved payment. I recommend you add fields as `:fees_payer`, `:senderEmail`, `:memo`...etc for more details.

Regards!